# Index nested lists of named data frames using character vector - R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, indexing

I have a nested list of named data frames like so:

```
mylist2 <- list(
  list(df1.a = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE))), df2.b = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE)))),
  list(df3.c = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE))), df4.d = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE)))),
  list(df5.e = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE))), df6.f = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE)))))
```

I run a test (not important what sort of test) and it produces a character vector telling me which data frames in this list are important:

```
test
[1] "df1.a" "df5.e"
```

What is the most efficient way to extract these data frames from the nested list using this character vector? The test only shows the names of second list, so `nestedlist[test]` does not work.

Comment: or `mylist2[names(mylist2) %in% test]`, or `mylist2[match(test, names(mylist2))]` Also: *"so something like mylist2[test[1]] would not be efficient"* What makes you think that?

Comment: Oh shoot! I dumbed down my example question too much. I actually have a list of lists of data frames. Not sure how to reproduce it simply but the problem is the elements of the list might be named `[[5]]df1.a, [[5]]df2.b, [[6]]df3.c, [[6]]df4.d` and the test only produces the names of the nested list (e.g. `df1.a`).

Comment: Try with `lapply(mylist2, '[', test)`

Comment: @akrun yes, that's it! I'll just update my question so you can post as an answer if you want. Thank you

Comment: Could you please check your example as I am not sure if that is the one that mimics your original data

Comment: @akrun thanks, edited now. :)

Comment: I was thinking that my original solution didn't work, so I updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP mentioned it was a nested `list`, we can loop through the initial `list` and then extract the elements of the second `list` with `[`

```
lapply(mylist2, '[', test)
```

---

or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(mylist2, ~ .x %>% 
                   select(test))
```

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset:

```
Filter(length, lapply(mylist2, function(x) x[intersect(test, names(x))]))
```

Comment: thank you very much, Sorry for the confusion. Your first and last answers work very well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reproducible example including sample data using nested `list`s:

```
# Sample data
lst <- list(
    list(df1.a = 1, df2.b = 2),
    list(df3.c = 3, df4.d = 4),
    list(df5.e = 5, df6.f = 6))
test <- c("df1.a", "df5.e");

ret <- lapply(lst, function(x) x[names(x) %in% test])
ret[sapply(ret, length) > 0];
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$df1.a
#[1] 1
# 
# 
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$df5.e
#[1] 5
```