# Change specific columns in list of data frames - R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

In a list of data frames: (`mylist<-list(iris, mtcars, ToothGrowth)`), how can I make a change only to specific columns within the list?

For example, I have a character vector (`test`) that gives the column names`"Petal.Width"` and `"drat"`. How can I match these names to column names in my list of data frames and apply something like `log(x + 1)`?

So far I am able to get the required columns [out on their own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765691/index-nested-lists-of-named-data-frames-using-character-vector-r?noredirect=1#comment86547446_49765691), but I'm not sure how to keep the whole list of data frames together and just alter a couple of columns. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd first define the function you want to apply, in your example `log(x + 1)`:

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  log(x + 1)
}
```

Then use `purrr::map` to go through the list and `dplyr::mutate_at` to match the column names:

```
library(tidyverse)
mylist %>% 
  map(~mutate_at(.x, vars(one_of(c("Petal.Width", "drat"))), myfun))
```

Note this will give warnings because not all data frames contain the columns. You could use `matches()` instead if the warnings bother you:

```
mylist %>% 
  map(~mutate_at(.x, vars(matches("^Petal\\.Width|drat$")), myfun))
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in couple of steps

```
test <- c("Petal.Width", "drat")

#Calculate the new value only for those specific columns which we need
value_cols <- lapply(mylist, function(x) log(x[names(x) %in% test]))
```

`value_cols` contains values for columns which we need to change.

We then use `mapply` and select specific columns from each list and update their values.

```
mapply(function(x, y) {
  x[names(x) %in% test] <- y
  x }, mylist, value_cols)
```

where `value_cols` is

```
value_cols
#[[1]]
#     Petal.Width
#1   -1.60943791
#2   -1.60943791
#3   -1.60943791
#4   -1.60943791
#5   -1.60943791
#...
#...
#[[2]]
#                    drat
#Mazda RX4           1.360977
#Mazda RX4 Wag       1.360977
#Datsun 710          1.348073
#Hornet 4 Drive      1.124930
#Hornet Sportabout   1.147402
#...
#...
#[[3]]
#data frame with 0 columns and 60 rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `intersect` with the names of the columns to avoid getting the warnings

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- mylist %>%
           map(~ .x %>%
                  mutate_at(vars(intersect(names(.), test)), myfun))
```

#### data

```
mylist<-list(iris, mtcars, ToothGrowth)
myfun <- function(x) {
 log(x + 1)
}

test <- c("Petal.Width", "drat")
```